# Feature deactivation doesn't work. Loads forever without performing deactivation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm experiencing problems when trying to deactivate a custom feature through the GUI. When I press the 'deactivate' button I'm, as expected, redirected to the warning page which asks if I'm sure I want to deactivate. 
Upon confirming, the page starts loading. 
The feature in question should normally be activated very fast, however on this occasion the page loads for more than 5 minutes without anything happening.
After concluding that the page seems to be stuck in an eternal loading cycle, I had to refresh the page to see if there had been any changes, but no, the feature remains active.

Any ideas?

Details:
The site I'm working is a previously existing office365 site. I've just made some changes to my custom solution (modifying one feature and adding another)deactivated the old solution and uploaded the new solution, so I'm trying to deactivate and reactivate the feature which I've modified.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what's happening during deactivation - 5 minutes might not be very long if the deactivation has to perform a lot of updates (e.g. removing columns from lists in lots of subsites). I did once have a feature deactivation that took 45 minutes (?) to run.

I guess another possibility is that you've got C# code that contains an infinite loop? Though that seems a bit of a long shot.

Otherwise, Office 365 is very hard to debug; I'd suggest raising a support call with Microsoft through the O365 portal to see if they can see any logs.

Answer (score 0):

When the feature is removed are you trying to remove items like CT's or anything that is dependant on another thing?

I've seen features get glitchy when this occurs on our test enviroment and make sure this is ironed out before deploying to live.

Theres a feature checker somewhere on codeplex but i'm not sure if this will connect to the office365 site. It's called something like FeatureAdmin.exe This might help you in removing the feature and clearing out left over stuff from the feature however it will not remove whatever your feature is struggling to remove(if it is of course!)

When the original feature was deployed did you test it could be deactivated cleanly?

Comment: The features really don't do anything on activation/deactivation. They are basically just event handlers for list items, so they shouldn't take much time at all during activation/deactivation.

Comment: I think you were meant to post this on the above post.

Comment: When the original feature was deployed did you test it could be deactivated cleanly?